# Select Multiple Div Cards Inside a Div Container/Wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm still new to JS and Jquery. So I have this coding challenge wherein I have to select mulitple cards and make sure that the background-color change on checking the Checkbox.

A little bit of idea is that I know I have to make sure that it is an array (I mean the cards). But for some reason I cannot wrap my head around it and I'm running out of ideas. Any help will be appreciated.

Here's my code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        .cards-wrapper {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            columns: 4;
        }

        .cards-wrapper .card {
            flex-grow: 1;
            margin: 10px;
            width: 150px;
        }

        .ui-selected {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="container-lg">
        <div class="cards-wrapper" id="card-div-wrapper">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="card-header-id">
                    <span>Sample Title</span>
                    <span style="float: right;"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-id"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="card-header-id">
                    <span>Sample Title</span>
                    <span style="float: right;"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-id"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="card-header-id">
                    <span>Sample Title</span>
                    <span style="float: right;"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-id"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="card-header-id">
                    <span>Sample Title</span>
                    <span style="float: right;"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-id"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let x = document.getElementById('card-div-wrapper').querySelectorAll('.card');
        let changeBg = document.getElementById('card-header-id');

        $().ready(function () {
            x.forEach(element => {
                $(element).click(function () { // i know this shouldn't be a click function I'm no sure
                    $(changeBg).click(function () { // this should be the click function that would change the bg
                        $(this).toggleClass("ui-selected");
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have a script error when trying to run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using same ids at multiple places which will not work as id attributes must be unique, also the css class `.ui-selected` needs to be more specific.

As for your event listener, you can add an `change` listener to the checkboxes and find the parent card using the jQuery `.closest()` method.

Here's a shorter working example with jQuery:

```js
$(() => {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", e => {
    $(e.target).closest(".card").toggleClass("ui-selected")
  })
})
```

```css
.cards-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  columns: 4;
}

.cards-wrapper .card {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 150px;
}

.card.ui-selected { /* This selector must be more specific */
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<section class="container-lg">
  <div class="cards-wrapper" id="card-div-wrapper">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <span>Sample Title</span>
        <span style="float: right;"><input type="checkbox"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <span>Sample Title</span>
        <span style="float: right;"><input type="checkbox"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <span>Sample Title</span>
        <span style="float: right;"><input type="checkbox"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <span>Sample Title</span>
        <span style="float: right;"><input type="checkbox"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```